# Error when concatenating strings in C

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am trying to join 2 strings in a char array, using the following code:

```
char url[300];
strcpy(url, "http://example.com/script.php?email=example@example.com");
char * mail = lpObj->Email;
strcat(url, mail);
```

I am running this on a VPS with Visual Studio, and my program always crashes and it goes to a file with asm code. `lpObj->Email;` is assigned and it has a well-formed string.

Does somebody knows why this happens?

Comment: C doesn't have exceptions.

Comment: In the debugger, when your program crashes, you look at the _call stack_ window, and click on the top function that is yours. This is where it crashed in your program.

Comment: Visual Studio runs on Windows, which has "exceptions" for fatal errors.  Would you complain if someone described C code causing a "segfault"?

Comment: If the error is really occurring on the strcat operation, then most likely "mail" has been assigned a bogus (possibly null) value.

Comment: @chris I am sorry, I am a C# developer and we use exceptions.

Comment: You could replace the entire fragment by `int rc; char url[300]; rc = snprintf(url, sizeof url, "%s%s", "http:...", lp->Email);` , and check the rc returnvalue.

Comment: @Pacha: I don't care if you use exceptions. I am a composer, and I use transpositions. Is that relevant? To C?

Comment: @Pacha - you'd have saved everyone a lot of time if you hadn't said the string was assigned and well formed, when it was actually a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two cases that will cause error, the first case is when `mail` is too large for the destination `url`. I was able to get this code to `seg fault` but the length required to achieve the overflow may vary:

```
char url[50];
strcpy(url, "http://example.com/script.php?email=example@example.com");
char  *mail = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
strcat(url, mail);
```

The second case is if `mail` is `NULL`:

```
char  *mail = NULL ; 
strcat(url, mail) ;
```

Comment: @Pacha happy I was able to help.